# Rewrite URL for file in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP file in: mydomain/components/com_cloakurl/cloakurl.php

I want to rewrite `mydomain/go/abc` to `mydomain/components/com_cloakurl/cloakurl.php?id=abc`

I tried:

`RewriteRule ^go/([/_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ components/com_cloakurl/cloakurl.php?id=$1`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesnt work? and where is your htaccess located?

Comment: When I go to mydomain/go/abc it shows blank page

Comment: Is "/components/com_cloakurl/cloakurl.php?id=abc" working when you enter it in browser?